# I need help making this shape with nested for loops [Update]

Tags: java, nested-loops

I need to print out this shape using nested for loops for **homework** (full disclosure.)
I cant figure out how to center the whole thing though.

[image]

The periods represent a continuation of the pattern.   So it's supposed to be the whole pyramid.

Here's what I have so **now**

```
    public static void question4(){

   int ix = 30;
for(int i = 1; i<=128; i=i*2){

// x is the number printed
//it gets the value from i,
  for (int g = ix; g>=0; g--){
      System.out.print(" ");
  }
  for (int x2 =1; x2<=i-1; x2=x2*2){

      System.out.print("   ");
      System.out.print(x2);

  }
  for (int x = i; x>=1; x=x/2){
      System.out.print("   ");
      System.out.print(x);

  }

 ix=ix-4;
  System.out.println();
```

}

Thanks for the help with the decrementing spaces, now the numbers themselves push the bottom rows over however.   I tried using the string.length command suggested by another user but it kept returning an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to set a spacer string that decrements as you go down the pyramid.

Comment: And you'll notice that the length of that spacer string will vary inversely with the length of the number string. You should be able to calculate a for loop based on this observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String spacer = "                         ";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 128; i = i * 2) {

            // x is the number printed
            // it gets the value from i,
            System.out.print(spacer);
            for (int x2 = 1; x2 <= i - 1; x2 = x2 * 2) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(x2);
            }
            for (int x = i; x >= 1; x = x / 2) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            if ((i * 2) < 10)
                spacer = spacer.substring(0, spacer.length() - 2);
            else if ((i * 2) < 100)
                spacer = spacer.substring(0, spacer.length() - 3);
            else
                spacer = spacer.substring(0, spacer.length() - 4);
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

This will create space for each row decreasing the space as you go down the triangle.

Gives this for output:

```
                      1
                    1 2 1
                  1 2 4 2 1
                1 2 4 8 4 2 1
             1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1
          1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1
       1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
   1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Comment: I ended up mimicking your code.   It worked better than another for loop.   It was just odd because we hadn't learned about substrings and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very easy to answer it. First check this code

```
    int spaces = 7;
    for(int i = 1; i<=128; i=i*2){

         for(int k=1;k<=spaces;k++)
              System.out.print("  ");
         spaces--;

    // x is the number printed
    //it gets the value from i,
      for (int x2 =1; x2<=i-1; x2=x2*2){

          System.out.print(" ");
          System.out.print(x2);

      }
      for (int x = i; x>=1; x=x/2){
          System.out.print(" ");
          System.out.print(x);

      }
      System.out.println();
}
```

As you can see whenever the first loop starts iterating, nested for loop for space start giving space before the another nested loop print the numbers. As the loop move further spaces will get decremented and your pyramid will grow eventually.

Comment: Try System.out.print not println.

Comment: Even if you do that it runs but the triangle is still not correct.

Comment: @brso05 lol it was just a silly mistake of `print` and `println`. My fast typing will kill me one day :P

Answer (score 0):

Although answered & accepted, here's a solution that prints a perfect pyramid with one for loop

```
public static void perfectPyramid() {
    int upLimit = 1024;
    int blankFieldWidth = String.valueOf(upLimit).length() + 1; // if upLimit is 3-digit, the blank field will be 4-blanks
    String blank = new String(new char[blankFieldWidth]).replace("\0", " "); //one-liner for creating a String by repeating another String a given number of times
    String numPart = "1" + new String(new char[blankFieldWidth - String.valueOf(blankFieldWidth - 1).length()]).replace("\0", " ");
    String previous = "-"; // dummy initial value
    for (int i = 1; i <= upLimit; i = i * 2) {
        int countOfBlankFields = (int) (Math.log(upLimit / i) / Math.log(2)); // the count of blank columns per row (one side only)
        String dynSpacer = new String(new char[blankFieldWidth - String.valueOf(i).length()]).replace("\0", " ");
        numPart = numPart.replace(previous,  previous +  i + dynSpacer + previous);
        String blanks = new String(new char[countOfBlankFields]).replace("\0", blank);
        String row = blanks + numPart + blanks;
        previous = i + dynSpacer;
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

it prints a pyramid taking into account the spaces

```
                                                  1                                                      
                                             1    2    1                                                 
                                        1    2    4    2    1                                            
                                   1    2    4    8    4    2    1                                       
                              1    2    4    8    16   8    4    2    1                                  
                         1    2    4    8    16   32   16   8    4    2    1                             
                    1    2    4    8    16   32   64   32   16   8    4    2    1                        
               1    2    4    8    16   32   64   128  64   32   16   8    4    2    1                   
          1    2    4    8    16   32   64   128  256  128  64   32   16   8    4    2    1              
     1    2    4    8    16   32   64   128  256  512  256  128  64   32   16   8    4    2    1         
1    2    4    8    16   32   64   128  256  512  1024 512  256  128  64   32   16   8    4    2    1
```

For what concerns the nested-loops, you can move from creating a row by replacing string into using a nested-for